# Why does not my code not ignore values in a list that are repeated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to not include values in 'd' that are repeated when I append them to a list. I dont want to include values that I have repeated in the depth list. What am I doing wrong?

```
depth = columns['i_depth']

for row in reader:
    r = float(row['roll'])
    p = float(row['pitch'])
    d = float(row['i_depth'])
    if 0.21 <= p <= 0.31:
            if -0.06 <= r <= 0.06:
                if 90 >= d >= 4:
                    if d not in depth: # this is the code I added to remove repeats
                        columns['i_depth'].append(row['i_depth'])
                        columns['irrad2'].append(row['sci_ocr504i_irrad2'])
                        columns['lon'].append(row['lon'])
                        columns['lat'].append(row['lat'])
```

Comment: probably floating point accuracy.

Comment: You test `if d not in depth`, but you never ADD `d` to `depth`. You should do `depth.append(d)`.

Comment: @Hugh but I add d  to depth with columns['depth'] and then set that to depth above

Comment: If you are concerned with uniqueness, why are you not using a Set? `set.add` is idempotent.

Comment: what is the type of columns? It looks like you're using a dataframe (or similar) of strings (based on your use of `float`) whereas d is a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you use 'float' while depth is another type.

Try this line instead:

```
if d not in [float(i) for i in depth]:
```

To be clear, it is not the right thing to do. Try to use the appropriate type from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Not sure if it is the simplest, but it works now.

```
depth = columns['i_depth']
temp = [] # added this
for row in reader:
    r = float(row['roll'])
    p = float(row['pitch'])
    d = float(row['i_depth'])
    if 0.21 <= p <= 0.31:
            if -0.06 <= r <= 0.06:
                if 90 >= d >= 4:
                    if d not in temp:
                        temp.append(d) # added this
                        columns['i_depth'].append(row['i_depth'])
                        columns['irrad2'].append(row['sci_ocr504i_irrad2'])
                        columns['lon'].append(row['lon'])
                        columns['lat'].append(row['lat'])
```

Comment: There is no good reason that this should work but that the code in the question did not. What are you not telling us?

Comment: Also, consider doing `if 0.21 <= p <= 0.31 and -0.06 <= r <= 0.06 and 4 <= d <= 90 and d not in ...:`. That way you only have one level of indentation.

Comment: @Elmex80s. I switched the order but not the sense of the relationships